# GIMP: TIFF save cannot handle indexed images with alpha channel

Tags: gimp

When I wanted to save TIFF file, I got this message box:

```
TIFF save cannot handle indexed images with alpha channel
```

Although I had no alpha layer.

Here is an [example](http://klimes.wz.cz/noty/haydn_bug_alpha.xcf) which cannot be exported to TIFF file because of a not-existing alpha channel

It seems to be a bug - I do not know - the only remedy is:

> Ebene/Ebene auf Bildgröße and export as TIFF afterwards.

Comment: Curios. Please file a bug report about this in Bugzilla, and attach an image that causes the error on export. This will help to get the bug researched and - hopefully - fixed: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=GIMP&component=Plugins&version=2.8.14

Comment: I removed the answer from your question. If you want to answer your own question, please create an answer for that! In this case another user did the job for you already including translation.

Answer (score 7):

If this doesn't work:

```
menu ⇒ image ⇒ fit canvas to layers
```

then try:

```
menu ⇒ image ⇒ flatten image
```

Answer (score 4):

Go to layers --> Transparency --> remove alfa channel then export your image.